# Swagger lists of generics have type "any" instead of appropriate type

Tags: swagger

I am using swagger-jaxrs_2.10.0 version 1.2.3 (just upgraded from 1.2.2 which had the same result)

If I have a class like this:

```
public class XXXResponse
{
    private List<Boolean> booleans;
    private List<Byte> bytes;
    private List<Short> shorts;
    private List<Integer> integers;
    private List<Long> longs;
    private List<Float> floats;
    private List<Double> doubles;
    private List<String> strings;
    private List<Date> dates;

    // set/get methods
}
```

Swagger reports it as:

```
{
  "integers": [
    "int"
  ],
  "bytes": [
    "any"
  ],
  "longs": [
    "any"
  ],
  "dates": [
    "any"
  ],
  "shorts": [
    "any"
  ],
  "strings": [
    "string"
  ],
  "doubles": [
    "any"
  ],
  "floats": [
    "any"
  ],
  "booleans": [
    "boolean"
  ]
}
```

What specific magic do I need to incant to make the "any" turn into the appropriate types?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that that configuring Jackson did the trick:

[JacksonJsonProvider.java](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/blob/master/samples/java-jaxrs/src/main/java/com/wordnik/swagger/sample/util/JacksonJsonProvider.java)

```
@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class JacksonJsonProvider extends JacksonJaxbJsonProvider 
{
    private static ObjectMapper commonMapper = null;

    public JacksonJsonProvider() 
    {
        if(commonMapper == null)
        {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

            mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
            mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_DEFAULT);
            mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
            mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);    
            commonMapper = mapper;
        }

        super.setMapper(commonMapper);
    }
}
```